# Is a promise object part of the browser api or is it javascript specific

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, webapi

I understand that a promise is an object. Question is, where does this object belong to or where is it created? I understand the XMR object is a browser object but is the promise object also a browser object? or is it a javascript object.

Comment: As of the relatively modern versions of the language, they're part of JavaScript.

Comment: What is “XMR”? Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#specifications)? It tells you which specification Promises are part of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of ES6 (ES2015), promises are built into the Javascript specification and implementations to that spec. Before that, there were separate (outside of the language itself) implementations.

By XMR, I'm guessing you meant to say XHR (XML Http Request) which has always just been a separate implementation in the browser, not part of the Javascript specification - sometimes referred to as a "host object" or "host implementation".